Haraka SMTP Server can not send email because unable to rename tmp file
I used Haraka as my smtp server. I added cron job to restart Haraka service regularly for freeing memory after sending tons of email.
I found in my logs, that sometimes Haraka unable to rename queue files and email did not sent.
[ERROR] [-] [core] [outbound] Unable to rename tmp file!: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/opt/smtp/haraka/queue/__tmp__.1722784803115_1722784803115_0_431971_7VjxRd_71_saas-hved-relay02' -> '/opt/smtp/haraka/queue/1722784803115_1722784803115_0_431971_7VjxRd_71_saas-hved-relay02

Why is this happenend? Is my regularly restarting task affects this occurrence?
I changed my cron job to restart Haraka in different period of execution, and the time Haraka unable to rename tmp file also changed.
